# Using CSS Floats and the problems with margins

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, margins

This has always stumped me. And I always thought there must be a better way to do it.

I usually end up having to do a style="margin-right 0px;" on the last div so it shows all three. But I would ideally just like for that to happen without that need.

How would you do it? (must support IE7)

Sample code follows this quick image I created to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve. image.

[image: lay out example]

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
}

.container div {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.container a {
    display: block; 
}

.clearfloats {
    clear: both;    
}

</style>

<div class="container">

    <div><img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a></div>
    <div><img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a></div>
    <div style="margin-right: 0px;"><img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a></div>
    <br class="clearfloats" />

    <div><img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a></div>
    <div><img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a></div>
    <div style="margin-right: 0px;"><img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a></div>
    <br class="clearfloats" />

</div>
```

Comment: i suggest you take a look at [this article](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) on how to create a list of item "tiles" with perfect alignment in rows. it also shows how to create a "sensible" mark-up that avoids clearing every row.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 supports the first-child pseudo selector, although is somewhat buggy.

If you float to the left, and use that to erase any left margin it should work.
You can also use the :after pseudo selector to clear the floats after a row division.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="holder">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="holder">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 400px;

    background: #505050;
}

.holder:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.item {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    background: #202020;
}

.item:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8h3zr/ provides a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is to add a new label after .contanier and before the divs.

For example:

```
<style>
.container {
    width: 400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.subContainer{
    width:460px;
}

.container div {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.container a {
    display: block; 
}

.clearfloats {
    clear: both;    
}

</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="subContainer">
        <div><img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a></div>
        <div><img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a></div>
        <div><img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a></div>
        <br class="clearfloats" />

        <div><img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a></div>
        <div><img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a></div>
        <div><img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a></div>
        <br class="clearfloats" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this kind of thing that's compatible as far back as IE7 is still... tables, I think.
It's not the nicest in terms of markup, but you're guaranteed that it will lay out properly.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="someimage.jpg" /><a href="#">some link</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```